# Bootstrap modal popup and fadeout after few seconds according to ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to display a bootstrap modal with success of a `ajax` request. Its working for me. But my problem is when I try to hide it after few seconds as soon as it triggered.

This is how I tried it.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "includes/process.php",
   data: $(".banner-form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
   success: function(data)
   {

        $("#myModal").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
            $("#myModal").modal('close');
        });
   }
 });
```

But this is not working properly when I submitting the form first time. After that when I submitting the form this modal is not popup. Can anybody tell me what is the reason for this?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried it with this question also, But I couldn't figure this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577491/how-to-automatically-close-bootstrap-3-modal-after-time-period

Comment: Ur modal created with html5 and css3?

Comment: Should be `.modal('hide')`, not `.modal('close')`

Answer (score 1):

Here it is,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'link/',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (s) {
        $('#MyModal').modal({
            show: false
        });
    },
    error: function (e) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
// wait until ajax request is done
}).done(function() {
// close the modal
  $('#myModal').modal('hide')
  // try this if above does not work!
  // $('#modal').modal('toggle');
});
```

Comment: is the id of the modal correct? unless you should us your html, we cannot help further.

Comment: have you tried toggle option? have you stripped your code so that it does not fade, but only try to close?

Comment: I want to close it with fade effect.

Comment: Does ajax return correctly? Does it fade at least? How are you opening that modal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72067/discussion-between-tnk-and-taesu).

Comment: Can I have chat with you?