# Show tooltip on page load then auto hide

Tags: html, jquery, function, tooltip

I would like to show 1 tooltip on page load and then have it hide after a few seconds AND/OR hide when another tooltip is hovered.

I have found a few ways to do this however I'm using an Elementor Addon as my tooltip so its nested in a few divs which has confused me.

When you hover on 'div.eael-tooltip' - 'span.eael-tooltip-text' shows ( This is what I would like to show automatically for a few seconds)

```
<div class="eael-tooltip">
<span class="eael-tooltip-content">
<img>
<p></p></span>
<span class="eael-tooltip-text eael-tooltip-right">
<p></p></span>
            </div>
```

I understand I'll probably need some jQuery for this, Would anyone be able to help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap to create a dialog box and close it after a time period:
Solution just here: [How to automatically close Bootstrap 3 modal after time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577491/how-to-automatically-close-bootstrap-3-modal-after-time-period)

Comment: This is to auto close. I would like to auto show. My tooltip is done via a widget in Elementor so this wont work